# "This", "that" and "it" difference

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, dummy-pronouns

I know the difference between "that" and "this" that "this" is used to point to something near you, while "that" is used to refer to something far from you, but in my sentences if I am not pointing to anything near or far from me if I am in my country speaking about a place which is far away from me which one should I use?

If I use "it", would there be any difference between "it" and "this/that"?

- *That/this/it* is my dream to visit France.
- *That/this/it* is a place I want to visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pronoun **it** is for a general statement.

1. It is my dream to visit France.
2. You and I are talking about France, and you then say:
   **That's my dream**, to visit France. That = what is being discussed or said by you to me.
3. **This dream** you have, to visit France, not **that other one** to visit Australia. Will it come true, do you think?

This and that can refer to something said, some experienced or some situation.
**that** is either something previously discussed or something further away in time.
**this** is something more present, as in 3) above. It is in contrast to some unnamed "that" that may not even be mentioned.

**Is this** clear to you now? :)

BUT:
It's my goal to move abroad.

**This or that** is something I have wanted to do for a long time....:).

this = this idea.

That=would refer to the entire thing, that thing I just said.

Comment: @AntoniaA Yes, exactly. Well done.

Comment: @AntoniaA We can delete all these comments now.