# They are with things/objects

Tags: pronouns

I'd like to ask about the usage of **they are** with things/objects.
Is the meaning the same as two other sentences? Can **they are** replace **those are/these are** with no difference in meaning? If not, what's the difference? I know that **These are/Those are** are used depending on how far the object is located.

**They are** books.

**Those are** books.

**These are** books.

To clarify, I'd like to give an example.

[image]

They __________ books.

Of course the answer is **They are books.**

If I replace the example with the sentence: **These are books.**, would the meaning remain the same as **They are books.**?

I guess that "they are" is neutral and can mean the same as these are/those are.

What do you think?

**They are books. = These are books.** in this example?
(books are near me)
**They are books. = Those are books.** if the books are far from me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [it VS. this Vs. that.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/159475/it-vs-this-vs-that) Also [What is difference between 'it' and 'this'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24981/) and [“This”, “that” and “it” difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/258063/) and [difference between “it” vs “this” vs “that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150296/) and [“It” instead of “this/that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/262531/) and [difference between “it” vs “this” vs “that”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/150296/) and...

Answer (score 1):

Because *they* doesn't carry any information about distance, its usually only appropriate in this context when the object has already been identified.

> 1. What are these **things**? **They** are books.

> 2. Where did you put **the English books**? **They** are on the top shelf.

---

You may often replace *they* with *these/those* when the sense of distance is appropriate:

> 1. What are these **things**? **These/those** are books.

Either is appropriate based on *your* distance from the books.

> 2. Where did you put **the English books**? **Those** are on the top shelf.

*Those* here implies "the English books, not the Math or History books." Additionally, *"these are over there"* would not be appropriate because you yourself are hopefully not on the bookshelf.

Answer (score 0):

A quick browse of the uses of **these** and **those** should answer your question.

The choice of pronoun depends on the situation.

A: What do have on top of the cupboard?
B: **They are books.**

A: What do you have in the boxes?
B: **Those are books in the far box. The other boxes are empty.**

A: What's in the parcels?
B: **These are books in the parcel I'm holding; those are glasses in the parcel on the floor**.

**These** = close to the speaker
**Those** = further away from the speaker, often being pointed to.
**They** = refers to some object/s that have already been identified.